# AWS Api gateway + Cloudfront redirected to the API gateway url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I created a new Cloudfront, and I entered my API Gateway domain name (I'm doing it to redirect the HTTP to HTTPS queries) and the Origin Path ( my stage ), and when I try to access the URL of my cloudfront url, I'm getting a 301 to the API Gateway url, with the Origin Path, for example https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/.

Did I miss something?

Comment: The redirect must be coming from API Gateway, so you should check the logs, there.  You set the Origin Path to `/prod`, correct?  Not `/prod/`.

Comment: you want to use custom domain as API URL like api.example.com to point to you https://54Fesefed.cloudfront.net/prod ?